What is the origin of this quote on telling a big lie?
The following quote appears on numerous sites on the internet

If you tell a big enough lie and tell it frequently enough, it will be
believed.

It seems to be most commonly attributed to Hitler, but never with a source. Examples can be found on the sites of US Medicine, Pinterest, Courier & Press and quotery.com, among others. Only the latter notes that the quote is unsourced. Brainy Quote lists the quote as 'unknown' while two Quora users attribute it to Nazi propaganda minister Josef Goebbels.
Interestingly, another Quora user came up with something similar from a book published in 1869:

If a lie is only printed often enough, it becomes a quasi-truth, and
if such a truth is repeated often enough, it becomes an article of
belief, a dogma, and men will die for it.

However, I'm more interested in the specific quote 'If you tell a big enough lie and tell it frequently enough, it will be believed' as there seems to be a lot of misinformation about it. Is there a reliable source for either Hitler or Goebbels, or did someone else say it? Perhaps it was just made up?

For future reference, this may look like a self-answer question. However, note the dates. This is rather an attempt to save a (very rare) good answer to a question that needed deletion.

SHORT ANSWER
This is a false quote which exists in many paraphrased forms, and various attributions as to who allegedly said this. The origin may be an OSS psychological profile of Hitler from 1943.
DETAILED ANSWER
The origin of this made-up quotation may be found in the idea of a 'big lie' — which is found in Mein Kampf where Hitler used to accuse the Jews of using this technique. This 'others tell the big-lie' was then picked up by Goebbels who then applied it to the English, emphasizing the idea of repeating it. In 1941, Goebbels wrote:

The English follow the principle that when one lies, one should lie big, and stick to it. They keep up their lies, even at the risk of  looking ridiculous.

This appeared in an article he wrote titled Aus Churchills Lügenfabrik (Churchill's Lie Factory), the full text of which can be found here.
On the 'big lie', Goebbels is also alleged to have said:

If you tell a lie big enough and keep repeating it, people will eventually come to believe it. The lie can be maintained only for such time as the State can shield the people from the political, economic and or military consequences of the lie. It thus becomes vitally important for the State to use all of its powers to repress dissent, for the truth is the mortal enemy of the lie, and thus by extension, the truth is the greatest enemy of the State.

This also appears to be a false quote, as this SE answer shows. The article False Nazi Quotations says that (in 2010), none of the internet sites or books using this quote gave a source.
The origin of the Hitler misquote may well be Walter Langer's 1943 OSS report A Psychological Analysis of Adolph Hitler where the author writes that one of Hitler's "primary rules" was

people will believe a big lie sooner than a little one; and if you repeat it frequently enough people will sooner or later believe it.

Langer is not quoting Hitler here. He is simply providing an analysis based on the evidence available to him.

So the Quote about the Lie is a lie, not a quote.

@KerryL Well put. That's about the sum of it.

Only a little lie.

I think there is a term (and if there isn't there should be) for such "quotes"/rules that serve as an example themselves. Kind of like autological but more broad.

"They keep up their lies, even at the risk of looking ridiculous." How prophetic. We now have politicians blatantly saying they didn't say something, when it has been recorded on video for posterity.

If someone says something in a slightly clumsy way, and someone else who read or heard that expresses the same concept in an almost identical fashion, and the latter version gets widely quoted, to whom should the popular quote be attributed?

Very interesting context. The original quote is often cited as if Hitler (or Goebbels) was saying it as an advice for his staff, how to conduct propaganda, but in fact he said it as an accusation about what his enemies are doing.

@supercat Good question. Maybe one for Language and Usage?
